# How to solve when sms authentication expired in firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

After distributing the application on the Google Play Store, there was a problem with phone number authentication. After entering the verification code, the following error occurs.

[firebase_auth/session-expired] The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.

How should I change my code to solve this problem?

###Code 1. verification screen

```
Future<void> verifyOtp(BuildContext context, String userOtp) async {
    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthViewModel>(context, listen: false);
    await authProvider.verifyOtp(
        context: context,
        verificationId: widget.verificationId,
        userOtp: userOtp,
        onSuccess: () async {
          // checking whether user exists in database or not
          bool userExists = await authProvider.checkExistingUser();
          if (userExists) {
            // user exists in our database
            await authProvider.getDataFromFirestore();
            await authProvider.saveDataToSP();
            await authProvider.setSignIn();
            if (!mounted) return;
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeMain()),
                (route) => false);
          } else {
            // user does not exist (new user)
            if (!mounted) return;

            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GenderSelection()),
                (route) => false);
          }
        });
  }
```

###Code 2. auth provider:

```
  // signin
  void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          throw Exception(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (verificationId, forceRecendingToken) async {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => InputVerificationNumber(
                verificationId: verificationId,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // ignore: unused_result
      showAlertDialog(
          context: context,
          title: 'Error',
          message: e.message ?? '에러가 발생했습니다. 개발팀에 문의해주세요.');
    }
  }

// verify otp
Future<void> verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: userOtp,
      );

      User? user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
      if (user != null) {
        // implement logic
        _uid = user.uid;
        await onSuccess();
      }

      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();

      await showOkAlertDialog(
          context: context, message: '로그인 과정에서 문제가 발생했습니다. \n$e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes. However I don't know it is a temporary solution or not. I changed  verificationCompleted to empty.
e.g. => verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async { // stay empty code }